# Implementing COM architecture with Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, com, client-server

As a mini project in MiddleWare we have to implement a client server architecture using visual C++ using COM for at least adding two numbers... my idea is to implement a chatting between client and server(asynchronous chatting. one after another)

I couldn't get much of a tutorial in the web. Can anyone know how to do this.?

Comment: Google for "atl COM tutorial".

Comment: Additionally, try to get the `Essential COM` book. First 4 chapters explain most of what you need to know.

Comment: I refer a code snippet in codeguru, it missing some details..... not showing what to do. (some images missing) and it's application is not running

Comment: First hint: try [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com) instead of CodeGuru. The people who started CodeGuru sold it and started CodeProject. CodeProject is what CodeGuru once aspired to be, but doesn't even aspire to any more.

Comment: but even their examples are too old and not working